# Adding Altitude to a marker in WebGLEarth

Tags: leaflet, javascript, markers, altitude

Im trying to add an altitude to a marker in [WebGLEarth](https://examples.webglearth.com) but i cant figure out how to do it. I cannot find anything in documentation either. The idea is that my markers act as satellites so i need the altitude from the earth.

```
//this doesnt work
var satellite_marker1 = WE.marker([0, 0], {elevation: 260.0}).addTo(earth);
```

If a marker is the wrong thing to use for this i have no issue using something that will work.

Comment: This is lacking context. What libraries are you using? What exactly is `WE`?

Comment: I couldnt add a tag but this is using WebGL, "WE" replaces "L" from the leaflet maps. http://examples.webglearth.com/

Comment: Note that WebGL and WebGLEarth are two **very** different things, and you didn't refer to WebGLEarth in your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply not doable in WebGLEarth (with its current API as of early 2019). As noted in the [project webpages](http://www.webglearth.org/api), WebGLEarth is a wrapper which simplifyes the [CesiumJS API](https://cesiumjs.org/) in order to create something that *looks like* the Leaflet API. One of those simplifications is the height of markers.

For this particular task, I'd suggest using the CesiumJS API directly, without the WebGLEarth wrapper. This would be done using a [billboard](https://cesium.com/docs/tutorials/creating-entities/#points-billboards-and-labels), and using the `height` parameter of the [`Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees()` method](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cartesian3.html#.fromDegrees) when defining the position of the entity associated with the billboard.

The alternative to using CesiumJS directly would be to actually modify the WebGLEarth API to implement this as a feature.